# CIL disassembly of a function parameter involving a ternary expression

Tags: c#, cil, disassembly

I struggle with the CIL disassembly of the parameter to the `WriteLine()` call in:

```
FileInfo path = new FileInfo(@"c:\a.txt");
Console.WriteLine("prefix: " + path != null ? path.FullName : "null");
```

**CIL dissasembly**

```
.locals init (
    [0] class [mscorlib]System.IO.FileInfo path
)

// ...

IL_000c: ldstr "prefix: "
IL_0011: ldloc.0
IL_0012: call string [mscorlib]System.String::Concat(object, object)
IL_0017: brtrue.s IL_0020

IL_0019: ldstr "null"
IL_001e: br.s IL_0026

IL_0020: ldloc.0
IL_0021: callvirt instance string [mscorlib]System.IO.FileSystemInfo::get_FullName()

IL_0026: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
```

It seems to me that `Concat` is called first, and only then is the ternary
operator evaluated. In particular:

**`IL_0012`** `Concat("prefix", path)` seems to be called,
**`IL_0012`** `brtrue.s IL_0020`   // branch based on the previous return value

- Why is `Concat` called with `path` as a parameter instead of `path.FullName`?
- Does `Concat` return `null`, if its first parameter is `null`? How does the
  compiler know that? (If I replace `+` with my own `plus(string, string)`, the
  disassembly to something I would rather expect.)

Could you please explain, how the disassembly handles the ternary parameter and the call to `WriteLine`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not a problem of the disassembly, it's a problem of operator precedence.

Your expression is evaluated as

```
("prefix: " + path != null) ? path : "null";
```

Not as

```
"prefix: " + (path != null ? path : "null");
```

as you seem to expect. Just use parentheses correctly and you'll be fine :)

In fact, it's a missed "optimization" on part of the compiler - since `string.Concat("prefix: ", whatever)` can *never* be null, you'll *always* get `path.FullName`. Of course, a ternary that only ever evaluates to one of its options is almost certainly a bug, so...